# Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) formatter messing up XML comments?

Tags: xml, eclipse, code-formatting

Our project has hundreds of comments within XML files.  Some of these are just dividers like this:

```
<!--
    ==============================================================================================
    Entity Manager Bean
    ==============================================================================================
-->
```

We use the XML autoformatter extensively and it always kept lines seperated, while at the same time word wrapping other lengthy comments.  Now in Helios, we get this:

```
<!--============================================================================================== Entity 
    Manager Bean ============================================================================================== -->
```

Unless we uncheck the new "Join Lines" feature under preferences->xml->xml files->editor.  But doing this means we lose the line wrapping feature.

Is this a big step backwards or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

That could very well be the result of [bug 260282](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=260282), which

- prevents formatting XML comment before the root element
- allows for comment formatting to be completely disabled and for lines to not be joined even if they don't exceed the line width limit.

So if the "not join the lines" isn't practical, all there is for now would be disabling XML comment formatting, which is not ideal...

[image]